# Knockout JS: checking for the existence of an observable in an IF binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm rendering a similar block of HTML for several slightly different objects. They're 90% the same, but each one has some specific quirks that demand extra observables. I would like to render each of these mostly-similar items in a template block, but I'm running into problems with undefined objects.

Basically, I want to check for the existence of an observable object before rendering it in the template.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: blocks">
<h2 data-bind="text: normalHeader"><h2>
<p data-bind="text: normalText"></p>
<!-- ko if: specialText --><p data-bind="text: specialText"></p><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

So if specialText doesn't exist (not just has no value, but doesn't exist at all) for that iteration of `blocks`, ignore the conditional. The error I'm getting is:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: specialText is not defined;
```

From what I understand of Knockout's "if" binding, it should work if the object returns any kind of false-like value, like null or undefined, which means that the if binding should gracefully fail, which it definitely isn't.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You might use the following approach:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
    <strong data-bind="text: Foo"></strong>
    <br />
    <!-- ko if: $data.hasOwnProperty("Bar") -->
        <p data-bind="text: Bar"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->​
```

I've posted a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Isis/MecNx/57/)**

Comment: however, of course it doesnt change if the property appears, as its not observable

Comment: it doesn't do what folks would normally want to do, "of course"? good one

Answer (score 10):

`<!-- ko if: typeof specialText != 'undefined' -->`

Based on Oybek's solution, you could also do:

```
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
    <strong data-bind="text: Foo"></strong>
    <br />
    <!-- ko if: "Bar" in $data -->
        <p data-bind="text: Bar"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->​
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/MecNx/56/

Comment: This also works, but the hasOwnProperty function is a bit cleaner; Thanks!

Comment: This solution handles polymorphic objects, while hasOwnProperty() will fail if the property you're looking for was added to a prototype. Excluding prototype properties with hasOwnProperty() is preferable when doing a for each, but in this use case I'd say straight up checking for 'undefined' is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by accessing through the object's indexer:

```html
<!-- ko foreach: Items -->
    <strong data-bind="text: Foo"></strong>
    <br />
    <!-- ko if: $data["Bar"] -->
        <p data-bind="text: Bar"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<!-- ko if: specialText != null -->
```

ko will recognise it as an expression rather than a value and so it *should* work as you want :)